# MySQL - return all records that have n amount of consecutive records after that match criteria

Tags: mysql

MySQL v5.5

Hi - I need to create a select query from a simple table where it returns all rows that have a certain amount of consecutive rows after, that are marked available.

Example table data is as follows:

```
id   Slot    Available
0    5.00pm  1
1    5.10pm  1   
2    5.20pm  1
3    5.30pm  0
4    5.40pm  1
5    5.50pm  1
6    6.00pm  1
7    6.10pm  1
```

I have a variable that will determine the number of slots needed.

So for example, if the variable is 3, I need the results to return all slots that have 2 consecutive slots available.

Desired outcome in this example would be:

```
id   Slot    Available
0    5.00pm  1
4    5.40pm  1
5    5.50pm  1
```

Any assistance would be greatly apprecaited.

(I'm not a professional developer so please be gentle :) )

Many thanks

Comment: Can you clarify or provide more examples? 1) What means "2 consecutive slots available"? I see that all slots is consecutive in the set and there are provides in the sort order. 2) Why exactly 2 consecutive slots, what means the "consecutive"? 3) Why in the desired solution returned 0,4,5 but not 0,1,7? What the difference?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a way to do what you want with SQL. I have an example of stored procedure you could use.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetTimeSlots;

CREATE PROCEDURE GetTimeSlots(NoOfSlots int)
BEGIN

    declare finished bool default false;

    -- stores id, slot and available from the cursor
    declare v_id int;
    declare v_slot text;
    declare v_available int;

    -- stores how many slots were found consecutively
    declare v_slotsfound int;

    -- loop through all available records
    declare c cursor for
    select id, slot, available from test where available = 1;

    declare continue handler for not found
    set finished = true;

    -- create empty table to store slots we find
    drop temporary table if exists tmp;
    create temporary table tmp
    select * from test where 1=2;

    open c;
    looper: loop
        fetch c into v_id, v_slot, v_available;
        if finished then
            leave looper;
        end if;

        select sum(case
                   when available then 1
                   else 0
                   end) into v_slotsfound
        from (
            -- list out as many slots you need
            -- outer query will total up the # of available slots
            select available from test where id >= v_id
            order by id
            limit NoOfSlots
        ) t;

        -- if # of available slots equals how many you want, store data
        -- in temporary table
        if v_slotsfound = NoOfSlots then
            insert into tmp values (v_id, v_slot, v_available);
        end if;

    end loop looper;
    close c;

    -- output the results
    select * from tmp;
    drop temporary table if exists tmp;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

## Run it

```
mysql> call gettimeslots(3);
+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | slot   | available |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    0 | 5.00pm |         1 |
|    4 | 5.40pm |         1 |
|    5 | 5.50pm |         1 |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

If you want 2 consecutive slots:

```
mysql> call gettimeslots(2);
+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | slot   | available |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    0 | 5.00pm |         1 |
|    1 | 5.10pm |         1 |
|    4 | 5.40pm |         1 |
|    5 | 5.50pm |         1 |
|    6 | 6.00pm |         1 |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

If you want 4 consecutive slots:

```
mysql> call gettimeslots(4);
+------+--------+-----------+
| id   | slot   | available |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    4 | 5.40pm |         1 |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

## Data used

```
create table test (id int, slot text, avaialable int);
insert into test values
(0,    '5.00pm', 1)
,(1,    '5.10pm',  1)   
,(2,    '5.20pm',  1)
,(3,    '5.30pm',  0)
,(4,    '5.40pm',  1)
,(5,    '5.50pm',  1)
,(6,    '6.00pm',  1)
,(7,    '6.10pm',  1);
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! One last thing, as I have absolutely no idea how it works, I just need to always include the first slot regardless of consecutive slots. Please could you point me in the right direction. Thank you again

Comment: Can you explain with an example what you mean @user1830274? You can edit your question and add an example. Show me what you want.

Comment: The code you've provided works perfectly, I just need to always return the first row (id 0) providing it is marked as available.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just above `select * from tmp;` line, type `insert into tmp select * from test where available = 1 limit 1;` That'll add the first available time slot above all the other lines. For good measure, you should also change `select * from tmp;` to `select * from tmp order by id`

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated

Comment: Absolutely. I liked the problem you were trying to solve. Thanks for sharing examples of what you were trying to do @user1830274

Comment: Is it easy enough to change it to return the last of the available slots, not the first? So if 1, 2, 3 are available, can it return 3 (not 1 as it does currently)?

Comment: Yeah, replace `insert into tmp values (v_id, v_slot, v_available);` with `insert into tmp select * from (select * from test where id >= v_id order by id limit NoOfSlots) t order by id desc limit 1;`

Comment: Legend! Thank you